# Correct way to launch a terminated app via a local notification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

Can we start running the app using Local Notification once the app is terminated?

My  problem is that when my app is in background and the local notifications come then the app works fine.

but once app is killed or terminated from background and then if local notifications come, then my app crashes.

What could be done?

Please Help and Suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in your

> didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

method in the app delegate you should handle launching the application if the local notification was received. Are you doing that?

Answer (score 0):

The area to look for is definitely ***launchOptions*** for **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**.